# Compile ffmpeg and x264 with --enable-shared

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, shared-libraries, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to compile ffmpeg with shared-library support, because when I compiled it statically it ended up making huge libraries, like `libavcodec.a` with 75MB in size. Any programs that I compiled against `libavcodec` was at least 50MB in size. This only happens on my RaspberryPi though, if I do

`ls -lsth $(which ffmpeg)`

on my RPI3 I get

`15M -rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 15M Jul 29 21:49 /home/pi/camiocam/cam/binaries/bin//ffmpeg`

While if I do the same on my macbook I get this output

`488 -r-xr-xr-x  1 john  admin   242K Jul 26 19:34 /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.1.1/bin/ffmpeg`

To get shared library support I did the following

```
# download and install libx264
cd ~/ffmpeg_build
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264.git
cd x264
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" ./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --enable-shared --disable-opencl
# PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make -j 8
# PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make install
# ldconfig
```

and ...

```
# to install ffmpeg

cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --arch=armel --target-os=linux --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --enable-pic  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-shared
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" make -j 8
```

Which gives this output

```
License: nonfree and unredistributable
Creating config.mak, config.h, and doc/config.texi...
config.h is unchanged
libavutil/avconfig.h is unchanged
libavcodec/bsf_list.c is unchanged
libavformat/protocol_list.c is unchanged
CC      libavcodec/libx264.o
POD     doc/ffprobe.pod
POD     doc/ffmpeg-all.pod
POD     doc/ffserver-all.pod
POD     doc/ffmpeg.pod
POD     doc/ffprobe-all.pod
POD     doc/ffserver.pod
MAN     doc/ffprobe.1
MAN     doc/ffmpeg.1
MAN     doc/ffserver.1
MAN     doc/ffmpeg-all.1
MAN     doc/ffprobe-all.1
MAN     doc/ffserver-all.1
GEN     libavcodec/libavcodec.ver
LD      libavcodec/libavcodec.so.57
AR      libavcodec/libavcodec.a
LD      libavformat/libavformat.so.57
LD      libavfilter/libavfilter.so.6
LD      libavdevice/libavdevice.so.57
library.mak:102: recipe for target 'libavdevice/libavdevice.so.57' failed
make: *** [libavdevice/libavdevice.so.57] Killed
make: *** Deleting file 'libavdevice/libavdevice.so.57'
```

I've tried to add the `--enable-pic` flag to the ffmpeg configure command but that made no difference.

Comment: You'll probably do better posting to the ffmpeg support website. Good luck.

Comment: What operating system? Jessie and lite both have ffmpeg preinstalled. Just type 'avconv'

Comment: @dbmitch `avconv` is not `ffmpeg`. jessie-backports has `ffmpeg` available.